# How to insert database values where form is dynamically generated

Tags: php, mysql

The form being used to populate the database has to be kept up to date with the respective fields within the database.

Therefore a dynamic form field is required:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Intermediate</th>
       <th>Advanced</th>
       <th>No selection</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
       $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SkillName FROM Skill");
       $sth->execute();
       $tempCounter = 1;

       while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
        echo ("<tr>
                <td colspan=\"3\">
                    <label for=\"td".$tempCounter."\">".$tempCounter.". ".$row['SkillName']."</label>
                </td>
            </tr>");

        echo ("
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type=\"radio\" name=\"".$row['SkillName']."\" id=\"tdA".$tempCounter."\" value=\"1\"/>
            </td>
            <td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"".$row['SkillName']."\" id=\"tdB".$tempCounter."\"  value=\"2\"/>
            </td>
            <td><input type=\"radio\"  name=\"".$row['SkillName']."\" id=\"tdC".$tempCounter."\" value=\"\" /></td>
        </tr>");
       $tempCounter++;
       }  
       ?>
 </table>
```

However, I don't know how to go about inserting data into the database when it is not clear what the data may be (specifically the SkillName)

In pseudocode it would be  `("INSERT INTO PersonSkill (PersonID, SkillName, SkillValue) values ($personid, $skillname, $skillvalue)")`

where `$personid` is already defined, `$skillname` is unknown at the time of writing the form, and `$skillvalue` is an integer.

So if the HTTP header information might look something like

```
 - [personid] => 101
 - [firstaid] => 2
 - [swimming] => 1
 - [mechanics] => 0
 - [firearms] =>
 - [athletics] => 2
```

How might I iterate over such values? I could always use the database itself to anticipate the values, but the final piece of the puzzle is eluding me...

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
if (isset($_POST[''.$row['SkillName'].''])) 
// And er... save some variable at this point I suppose, or perhaps append to an array...
}
```

Comment: Is storing the skillname into a session for future use a viable option?

Comment: @Kepoly I could do that... but that would only be deferring the problem, surely?

Comment: How do you plan to insert?  Button Click?  Jquery?  Forms Post?  I assume post "isset($_POST", but just want to make sure.

Comment: @jmcclure ah yes; post it is (form backend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your `skill` `inputs` into an `array`:

```
<input type=\"radio\" name=\"skill[".$row['SkillName']."\]" id=\"tdA".$tempCounter."\" value=\"1\"/>
```

So you can build your query in the page it posts to (since I understood from reading comments on your question that you do this):

```
$query = '
    INSERT INTO
        PersonSkill 
    (
        "PersonID",
        "'.implode('","', array_keys($_POST['skill'])).'"
    )
    VALUES
    (
        '.$personid.',
        "'.implode('","', array_values($_POST['skill'])).'"
    )
';
```

It should output something like this, if you left `firearms` on an empty value and chose 2 for `dance` in the form:

```
string(195) "
    INSERT INTO
        PersonSkill 
    (
        "PersonID",
        "firearms","dance"
    )
    VALUES
    (
        69,
        "","2"
    )
"
```

However, if you don't want to post the empty values you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to clean them out:

```
$skills = array_filter($_POST['skill']); 

$query = '
    INSERT INTO
        PersonSkill 
    (
        "PersonID",
        "'.implode('","', array_keys($skills)).'"
    )
    VALUES
    (
        '.$personid.',
        "'.implode('","', array_values($skills)).'"
    )
';
```

Unless I misunderstood you of course. Note: This is just an example. At least [`escape`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) your variables.

Answer (score 1):

How about looping through the POST vars instead, and inserting them using $key => $value

```
foreach($_POST as $skillname => $skillvalue){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO PersonSkill (PersonID, SkillName, SkillValue) values $personid, $skillname, $skillvalue);";

}
```